# Is it possible an address would have two types of balance?

Tags: solidity, addresses, balances

I have developed a smart contract such that there are two types of tokens i.e. energy and power. I need to transfer each of them separately to an account address and as a result each address needs to have these two values (energy and power).

But when I define two types of balances for an address, i receive the following error :

```
Error: Undeclared identifier. Did you mean "balances"?
    return balancesPw[_owner];
```

I defined balances as follows:

```
mapping(address => uint256) balances;
mapping(address => uint256) Pwbalances;
```

Comment: It looks like you declared a variable called `Pwbalances` but then tried to use one called `balancesPw` (which doesn't exist).

Comment: Or you could go crazy and use a `struct` for each address instead of multiple `mapping`. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity/13168#13168

Comment: Tank you it is ok